# Using Amazon EFS to share sources between webservers

Tags: amazon-web-services, webserver, hosting, amazon-efs

At the moment i am using some webservers (let's say two) for hosting different websites for my clients. Some of the websites were hosted on webserver A, the others on webserver B.

It is unhandy because everytime i want to upload something i have to lookup the correct ftp server.

Is it a good solution to make the sources (php files, images etc.) accessible for all webservers with the new Amazon EFS service?

Or is there another solution? Mirrors and complex CI are no options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cost is not your concern then EFS is the best option. You can achieve this using S3 too by mounting a S3 bucket onto your EC2 instance.

https://www.emfluence.com/blog/amazon-web-services-integrating-s3-and-ec2-few-simple-steps#gref

Comment: Can i mount a S3 bucket onto multiple EC2 instances? With EFS it's possible. Moreover EFS is a real filesystem.

Comment: If your application needs high performance read and write then S3 is not a good option EFS is best option. Only issue with EFS is it is more costly.

Comment: I would save all application sources (php files) in the EFS, so that the sources were available for every instance. Is EFS fast enough for that?